# How to do memoization in C++ using maps or vectors for arbitrary number of inputs?

Tags: c++, memoization

I tried using arrays but I don't need every single element, and so it won't compile because my bounds are too large.

So, I want to try something more dynamic, perhaps using a map or a vector or something (whatever you guys recommend).

Like I have a function:

```
long long func(long long arg1, long long arg2, long long arg3){
      check if [arg1, arg2, arg3] is memoized, and if it is, return it
      ....function body...
      store return value with [arg1, arg2, arg3] in memoization cache
      return value;
  }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to map `pair<pair<long long, long long>, long long>` to `long long`.

If you want to check whether the key is there or not, just use [find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/). Assigning and accessing key that you confirm exists in the map can be done safely with `[]` overloaded operator.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can define your own structure that contains the 3 `long long` keys, and define their natural ordering (for `map` to work correctly). Then you can avoid the lengthy `pair` syntax.

Comment: How would I initialize that / check if a value exists in such a cache?

Comment: No, I'm not doing it for any competition or contest.

Comment: I don't think I can just use []. With pairs, don't you need to do .first .second?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: You can pass in a `pair<pair<long long, long long>, long long>` as key to `find()` or `[]`.

Comment: That isn't really what I was getting at, but thanks anyway. I think I'll need to use another data structure for this

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: If you can define your own structure and put the 3 `long long` into the structure, you can avoid the lengthy `pair` construct.

Comment: I try map< pair< pair<ll,ll>, ll> > cache; and it does not compile

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: Since you are mapping from triple -> value, the syntax should be: `map<pair<pair<ll,ll>,ll>, ll>`. The iterator returned by `find()` will be a quadruple `pair< pair<pair<ll,ll>,ll> , ll>`.

Comment: Note in C++11 you can simply do `std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>`.